# Why does my MultiDataTrigger run only once even if it satisfies the conditions?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In an attempt to further reduce my c# code, I've tried handling the Hamburger Menu's animation on XAML. I've applied a MultiDataTrigger with a condition that takes the current Width and the Button press from the Hamburger Menu Button. It animates the first Width 70 -> 150 and Width 150 -> 70 but after that it doesn't work anymore.

```
    <Grid x:Name="NavigationGrid" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Black">
    <StackPanel Margin="0">
        <Button x:Name="HamburgerMenuBtn" Style="{DynamicResource NavigationBtn_Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="70"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=NavigationGrid,Path=ActualWidth}" Value="70"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=HamburgerMenuBtn,Path=IsPressed}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                        From="70"
                                        To="150"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=NavigationGrid,Path=ActualWidth}" Value="150"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=HamburgerMenuBtn,Path=IsPressed}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                        From="150"
                                        To="70"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Comment: try using the visual tree and the property explorer to see if all your conditions are really fulfilled. Also you should add a StopStoryboard tag in the ExitActions of the MultiDataTrigger so the animation actually ends and does not block the element from beeing animated again.

Answer (score 0):

IsPressed is only true momentarily. Lose that second animation. Just use the first animation but make it reverse. So it grows then reduces the size. AutoReverse="true".

You might also have to increase duration a little.